# Why is converting my float to an int making the number negative?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, int, nstimeinterval

```
NSTimeInterval expirationTime = (secondsSinceUnixEpoch*1000)+120000;
expirationTime = ceil(expirationTime/2);
int expirationInt = (int)expirationTime;
NSLog(@"%d", expirationInt);
```

The log output is always negative, even though before I convert it to an int it's positive... I tried just multiplying it by -1 to make it positive again and it's just staying negative! I'm totally perplexed.... don't know much about C, am I just doing something silly??

Comment: Have you considered overflow?

Comment: Why are you converting it to an `int`? Why not keep it as an `NSTimeInterval` (`double`)?

Comment: Try using `long` or `long long` if you really need an integral type.

Comment: Because I need it to not have decimal points. I'm putting the number into a URL. Is there a better way to get the decimal part out than converting it to int?

Comment: I will try with long, thank you!

Comment: The maximum `int` is about 2 billion.  The current Unix epoch time in seconds is 1,384,381,689.  Convert to milliseconds (as you have) and you add another 3 digits on the right.

Comment: @user1714556 I posted an answer that shows how to use the `NSTimeInterval` in a URL without the need to convert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number `(secondsSinceUnixEpoch*1000)+120000` looks to me like it's going to be way too large to fit in an `int`.  Chances are the integer is overflowing and becoming negative.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to `long long` is one solution. As you stated in a comment, you want to show a whole number for use in a URL. Just do this:

```
NSTimeInterval expirationTime = (secondsSinceUnixEpoch*1000)+120000;
expirationTime = ceil(expirationTime/2);
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com?time=%.0f", expirationTime];
```

This will format the decimal number as a whole number.

Comment: So simple! Kent Beck “Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work”